# Accessing REST API via .net VB code on Server 2012 R2 generates a SSL/TLS error

Tags: vb.net, ssl

I am getting this error when I am accessing a REST API in woocommerce:-

"Unable to write data to the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host."

Or

This error:-

"The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel."

***Please note I only get this error on the Server 2012 R2 machine on my windows 10 machine no error.***

This is the .net vb code I have before accessing the API.

`ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls Or SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 Or SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 Or SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3`

Is the code above sufficient ?

There is literally thousands on references to this error but none has a specific answer. I even tried using a program called IISCrypto that sets various ciphers; to no avail.

Comment: You probably don't have required Cipher Suites in that other System. See [Cipher Suites in TLS/SSL (Schannel SSP)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/cipher-suites-in-schannel) and [Protocols in TLS/SSL (Schannel SSP)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/protocols-in-tls-ssl--schannel-ssp-) -- Use a Proxy (Fiddler / WireShark) that logs the details of the SSL handshake exchange

Comment: Also, get [IIS Crypto](https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto/) (free software) and check what's enabled / available in the System that fails. You can also test a connection -- If you decide to force a Protocol, make sure it just `SecurityProtocolType.Tls12`

Comment: Please note that Windows Server 2012 R2 was pretty much [end-of-life](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/windows-server-2012-r2) four years ago. You should not be using it.

Comment: I tried using my API with a different WooCommerce website and it worked - when I use it on this website (www.streetgym.co.za) it fails with the error I mentioned in my Question. What must I do/check on the website to get it working.

Comment: You haven't mentioned which version of .NET Framework that you're using, but the following may be helpful: [Transport Layer Security (TLS) best practices with the .NET Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls)

Comment: I have .net 4.5 / 5.0 /6.0 on the server 2012 r2

Comment: When I try to install 4.72 its says I already have a higher version

Comment: On Windows Server 2012 R2, you have to [enable TLS1.2](https://serverfault.com/questions/1099148/windows-server-2012-r2-tls-1-2-issue). See also [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/update-to-enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-as-default-secure-protocols-in-winhttp-in-windows-c4bd73d2-31d7-761e-0178-11268bb10392)

Comment: Has been enabled - got a feeling it has to do something with the www.streetgym.co.za certificate - what I don't know as other sites work with the API settings as I coded.

Comment: @BASitBulbulia - See my posted answer -- there may be nothing wrong with your certificate -- the trick is to set the security protocol to a SINGLE protocol (TLS 1.2) as per the code I have posted as setting to multiple protocols will result in the exception you are seeing.

Answer (score 0):

You may find the following useful:
https://www.hass.de/content/setup-microsoft-windows-or-iis-ssl-perfect-forward-secrecy-and-tls-12

Also - I dug up some old code that was used on Windows 2012 R2 to enable TLS 1.2, see below:

```
      Dim bypass_ssl_validation As Boolean

      Dim security_protocols As System.Net.SecurityProtocolType


      ' Set the following flag to true to bypass SSL certificate validation; if any
      ' errors are encountered with SSL, they will be ignored.  This may need to be
      ' done in cases where a protocol mismatch error occurs or the remote servers
      ' SSL certificate has expired ...

      bypass_ssl_validation = True

      Try

         ' Get current security protocols ...

         security_protocols = System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol


         ' Set security protocol to TLS 1.2 only ...
         ' NOTE: If more than one protocol is enabled when we try to post,
         '       the call will fail with the following exception:
         '       System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.

         System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12


         ' If flag set - bypass SSL Certificate Validation Checking.
         ' Note that this is a Shared property on the 'ServicePointManager' object, and must 
         ' then persist for the entire application, which we probably do not want -- so set 
         ' back to default behavior and end of try block ...

         If ( bypass_ssl_validation ) Then

            System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = AddressOf validate_remote_certificate

         End If

         ' POST data as needed ...

      Catch ex as Exception

         ' Log / report error ...

      Finally

         ' Restore previous protocols ...

         System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = security_protocols

         ' If we bypassed SSL validation, restore default behavior ...

         If ( bypass_ssl_validation ) Then

            System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = Nothing

         End If

      End Try



   '-------------------------------------------------
   ' Delegate to ignore SSL Certificate errors if need
   ' be. Used when configuring ServicePointManager ...
   '
   Public Shared Function validate_remote_certificate( ByVal sender As Object, _
                                                       ByVal certificate As X509Certificate, _
                                                       ByVal chain As X509Chain, _
                                                       ByVal ssl_policy_errors As SslPolicyErrors ) As Boolean

      Return True

   End Function
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work !

Comment: Did you try the code posted? .. and what exception was reported?

Comment: Yes I have ----> This error :-
The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.

Comment: @BASitBulbulia - I have updated my code sample to bypass SSL Certificate errors -- give that a try.

Comment: @BASitBulbulia - You may also be able to check the SslPolicyErrors enumeration to help figure out what is going wrong -- hope that helps.